# Values are not getting stored in HashMap

Tags: java, hashmap

I'm trying to save a table value in hashmap while doing so only the last value if getting saved.That is it is resetting the already stored value In the HashMap. Table is:

> ```
>   | pageNumber | 1 |
>   | pageSize   | 40 |
> ```

That is pageSize=40
in this case. Here is my code:

```
for (int i=0; i<params.size(); i++)
{
    queries = new HashMap<String,Object>();
    queries.put(params.get(i).get(0), params.get(i).get(1));
    System.out.println("Value of column: " + params.get(i).get(0));
    System.out.println("Value of row: " + params.get(i).get(1));
    System.out.println("values of the new hashmap is: " + queries);
}
```

I'm not getting what exactly I'm doing wrong here.

Comment: You are creating a new HashMap in each iteration of your loop. Move queries = new HashMap<String,Object>(); outside the loop

Comment: You keep replacing `queries` with a new **empty** map, so at the end, only the last parameter will be in that last map. Move `queries = new HashMap<String,Object>();` outside the loop.

Comment: Oh Yes!! I just noticed it. I put it outside the loop and it is working fine. Thanks, @Eran for helping.

Answer (score 2):

It should be

```
Map<String, Object> queries = new HashMap<>();

for (int i=0; i<params.size(); i++) {
    queries.put(params.get(i).get(0), params.get(i).get(1));
    System.out.println("Value of column: " + params.get(i).get(0));
    System.out.println("Value of row: " + params.get(i).get(1));
    System.out.println("values of the new hashmap is: " + queries);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are creating a new object of hashmap again and again in a loop. To fix this you can do as follows:-

```
Map<String,Object> queries = new HashMap<String,Object>();
for (int i=0; i<params.size(); i++)
{
    queries.put(params.get(i).get(0), params.get(i).get(1));
    System.out.println("Value of column: " + params.get(i).get(0));
    System.out.println("Value of row: " + params.get(i).get(1));
    System.out.println("values of the new hashmap is: " + queries);
}
```